# Fairness and guaranteed output delivery

Tags: provable-security, protocol-analysis, security-definition

Why for achieving the **fairness** and **guaranteed output delivery**, less than a half of the parties should be corrupted? ($t < m/2$, where $t$ is the number of corrupted parties and $m$ is the total number of the involved parties)

Would you please prove it intuitively?

Comment: You will never reach true understanding if you ask for "intuitive proofs" of everything. Formal proofs exist for a reason.

Comment: @fkraiem Could you please give me a formal proof?

Comment: You have been somewhat monopolizing the site, with 14 questions in a few days (plus follow-up questions on every answer). Your questions show confusion about very fundamental aspects of MPC. If you really want to understand MPC, you need to *slow down* so you have time to process. You cannot crowdsource every single step in understanding. Maybe the books are not a good fit and you would get more by watching some tutorial lectures (e.g., Bar-Ilan winter schools).

Comment: @Mikero Thanks a lot for considering my question. I have just put my questions here, but I did not force anyone to answer my questions. If you and anybody else get a chance, please steer me in a right direction. Thank you, Mikero

Comment: @Mikero Would you please show me the rules about the number of questions that I can put on this site? Where are the rules? I want to read them. Thanks for considering my questions.

Comment: I never said it was against site rules to ask so many questions. I am trying to steer you in a right direction by suggesting that you slow down and make a serious effort to understand one thing before moving on to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively anything the honest minority can do the dishonest majority can do as well. So if the minority can force a correct outcome the majority can force an incorrect outcome.

Side note:The question is ill-defined, not mentioning a specific problem where these requirements are to be held, is this a computation? who has the input? In some situations we can deal with a dishonest majority such as limiting them to no more than failing the process.